# Webforms routing - populate hyperlink NavigateUrl with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using a linkbutton for this so I know that I can postback and perhaps redirect, however I'd prefer to do this directly using a hyperlink is possible.

I have a route setup with parameters:

```
href='<%$RouteUrl:RouteName=Apply, Amount=1234  %>'></a>
```

The issue I have is that I'm using jquery to update some textbox fields - so the user slides a slider, which updates a textbox. jQuery needn't be part of the equation because the user could also enter a value directly in the textbox.

What I want to achieve is that the amount param is dynamically inserted somehow into the the href value - almost like an embed block within an embed block. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not nicely. You have two options: 1) On each input update do an ajax round trip to server to get a new URL. That takes time and requires you to have a webmethod, but helps keeping a nice consistent way of creating urls from routes; 2) Forget about routes and modify url with javascript directly. Not nice, but relatively easy

Comment: Thanks for your input Andrei - I guessed as much, but wasn't sure.